# Plotting the intervals counts

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created intervals and the count under these intervals.

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['a'],[0,2,4,6,8])).count()
```

I'm trying to make a bar graph of this using `sns.countplot`, but doesn't seem to give me the right output. Is there any other way of making a barplot of these intervals counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Pandas:

```
pd.cut(df['a'],[0,2,4,6,8]).value_counts().plot.bar()
```